# Connecting Spark and elasticsearch

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I'am trying to run a simple code of Spark that copies the content of an RDD into an elastic search document. Both spark and elastic search are installed on my local machine.

```
    import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

    object ES {

   case class Person(ID: Int, name: String, age: Int, numFriends: 
  Int);

     def mapper(line: String): Person = {
    val fields = line.split(',')
    val person: Person = Person(fields(0).toInt, fields(1), 
    fields(2).toInt, fields(3).toInt)
    return person}

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark: SparkSession =
    SparkSession
    .builder().master("local[*]")
    .appName("SparkEs")
       .config("es.index.auto.create", "true")
       .config("es.nodes","localhost:9200")
     .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val lines = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/home/herch/fakefriends.csv")
val people = lines.map(mapper).toDF()

people.saveToEs("spark/people")

}

}
```

I'am Getting this error. After multiples retries

```
 INFO HttpMethodDirector: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) 
 caught when processing request:Connection timed out (Connection timed 
 out)

 INFO HttpMethodDirector: Retrying request

 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (runJob at EsSparkSQL.scala:97) 
 failed in 525.902 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 
 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in 
 stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): 
 org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: 
 Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes 
 failed; tried [[192.168.0.22:9200]]
```

It seems to be a connection problem but i cannot identify its cause. Elastic search is running on my local machine on localhost:9200 and i'am able to query it via the terminal.

Comment: Is spark actually fails to connect, or it loses connection later due to ES becoming non-responsive during operation or some other issue? Do you see any data being ingested into ES at all?

Comment: I think that it does not connect at all because the index do not get created.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running both locally, you need to set `es.nodes.wan.only` to `true` (default `false`) in your SparkConf. I ran into the same exact problem and that fixed it.

See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

As seen on the [elasticsearch / spark connector documentation page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html), you need to separate the host and port arguments inside the configuration :

```
val options13 = Map("path" -> "spark/index",
                "pushdown" -> "true",
                "es.nodes" -> "someNode", "es.port" -> "9200")
```

See how `es.nodes` only contains the host name, and `es.port` contains the HTTP port.

Comment: From documentation  "Each node can also have its HTTP/REST port specified individually (e.g. mynode:9600)". However i tried  : val elasticConf: Map[String, String] = Map("es.nodes" -> "127.0.0.1",
      "es.port" -> "9200") people.saveToEs("spark/people", elasticConf). But same issue.

Comment: @a-herch Can you make sure the es.nodes your are using is the same as the `http.host` in the `elasticsearch.yml` file of the config folder of elasticsearch ? Otherwise make it be the same as `network.host`, the idea being you have to make sure that the server is correctly bound to what Spark tries to connect-to.